# Using virtual link to plan with MoveIt

Tags: moveit, ros-humble

I want to plan paths with MoveIt using different planning groups. One of the groups is for a gripper type OnRobot RG6. In order to plan with the gripper I've created a 'virtual' link ergo a link without any collision, visual and only a tiny amount of mass. This link should at all time in the middle of the gripper equal distant away from the gripper fingers and at the height of the contact area of the gripper. I've set up a prismatic joint from the corpus of the gripper to the virtual grip point link. This joint is a passive joint, since I've to calculate the distance myself and publish it to `/joint_states`. However, I'm able to see in RViz, that the passive joint is not moving when I publish its values.

Is it generally possible to use such a passive joint as planning group tip?